# Get data from php using jquery then pass again to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Here's my setup:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li data-owner="93"><a href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li>
        <li data-owner="94"><a href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li>
        <li data-owner="95"><a href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="below_list">
        <div class="popup">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="popup-close">
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/close.jpg">
            </a>
            <div class="slider-wrapper">
                <div class="slider-inner">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/slider.png" />
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/slider2.png" />
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/slider3.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <h1 class="title"></h1>
                <h3 class="subtitle"></h3>
                <p class="description"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I click on the list item, I will get the data-owner using: `var formId = $(this).attr('data-owner');`. This will serve as the ID.

Then I will have to append to the blank `h1` using `$('.title').append('<?php echo get_the_title(formId); ?>');`

I understand PHP only executes once but I'm not sure on how to come up with a solution.

Note that everything occurs in one page without having to refresh.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: `I understand PHP only executes once` I think you need to understand more of what is going on. You need a good grasp of the fundamentals before asking for specifics.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use ajax for this.
Your php is initially processed on the page load. But any thing after that will not be processed.
Check the guides on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/.

You will need to pass the selected id to another php page (backend.php in this example), get it to process (in your case get the title), and echo the result in the backend.php.

A sample code would look like below.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "backend.php",
    data:"id="+formId , //add the variable you need to pass to the backend.php
    success: function(html){
        $("#response").html(data); //shows the output given in the backend.php in the response div.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call ajax twice

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'a.php',
        data: {name: 'xxxxxx'},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){

            // do stuff

            // call next ajax function
            $.ajax({ ....call to b.php....});
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to just change the `h1` text alone without any database change you can use

```
$('.container ul li').on('click',function(){
      var formId = $(this).attr('data-owner');
      $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url: "saveData.php",
          data:"formId="+formId ,
          success: function(data){
               $(".title").text(data); 
          }
      });

});
```

In `saveData.php`

```
<?php
```

//You can get your formID using `$_POST['formId'];`

```
$formId = $_POST['formId'];
```

//Write the `query` for getting the data from the `database` for the appropriate `formId`

//Then `echo` the title you obtained from the `query` result like

```
echo $formTitle;
```

This data will be available in the `ajax success`

Hope this helps u mate.. :)